# Value is not returned

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am beginner at JavaScript and I faced the confusion with the way how return works in JavaScript, that is, if you look at the code below I want to get value 5 when mirzhal method is called but I get nothing thus I need your help

```
let mir = {
    mirzhal() {
        function m() {
            let mi = 5;
            return alert(mi);
        }
        return m;
    }
}

mir.mirzhal();
```

Comment: `mir.mirzhal()();` should do it as `mirzhal` returns another function :)

Comment: you have to call the return value `mir.mirzhal()()`

Comment: `return alert(mi);` wont work, use `return 5;` then alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `5` from `m` function and also need to call the returned function

```js
let mir = {
    mirzhal() {
        function m() {
            let mi = 5;
            return mi;
        }
        return m;
    }
}

console.log(mir.mirzhal()());
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments and if you do not mind I would like to explain to you in an abstract manner the way I understood the return. So, in the code where I wrote return mi then mi is kinda put inside function m(). Then, since mi is inside m(), I return m which is then put inside mirhal(). Did I get the concept of return right?:) I will wait for your kind reply

Comment: @mirzhal `mir` is an object so `mirzhal` is an property on that and on function call it returns `function m` as return value and again when you do function invocation on returned value then you get the value `mi`

Answer (score 1):

`return` will return whatever is on the right-hand side of it.

If you want to get `5` then you need to return `5`.

```
return 5
```

… and you also need to **examine** the return value:

```
const five = mir.mirzhal();
alert(five);
```

---

Your current code doesn't return 5. It returns a function.

If you were to call that function, then it would alert 5 (and return the return value of that function).

```
const a_function =  mir.mirzhal();
a_function();
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments and please can I explain to you how I got the concept of return so that you can tell if it is correct or not. So, in the code where I wrote return mi,  mi is kinda put inside function m(). Then, since mi is inside m(), I return m (holding value of mi) which is then put inside mirhal(). Did I get the concept of return right?:)

Comment: @mirzhal — In the code you wrote, you never return `mi` at all. You define it in a function. You pass it to `alert`. That is everything that happens to `mi`. It doesn't exist until the function `m` is called, and it stops existing when the function finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your problems:

- in function `m`, you return the result of `alert(mi)` which is undefined (= nothing is javascript)
- in function mirzhal you return a function, so when you execute `mirzhal()` your result is a function you need to call.

`mir.mirzhal()();` will work

This should be better:

```
let mir = {
    mirzhal() {
        return 5;
    }
}

mir.mirzhal();
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because the function mirzhal() returns another function.

Try like this:

```
mir.mirzhal()();
```

And you can see you alert

Another problem is you try to return result from alert function which does not provide result